# How to disable Chromium.ChromeDriver wanting to reset Chrome settings at the beginnnig of Specflow test

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, chromium, specflow

[SpecFlow + Selenium + Chromium.ChromeDriver.2.29 wants to reset Chrome settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdMm3.png)

Hi !

Can someone please help me with this:

When SpecFlow + NUnit + Selenium + Chromium.ChromeDriver.2.29 tests are ran on Chrome,
in first tab of window appears “System Center Endpoint Protection wants to reset your settings”. In second tab application under test opens.
If I click "Reset" or "Cancel", it doesn't change anything - same thing appears in next  test run (test wants to reset Chrome settings).

I used driver = new ChromeDriver();

How can I disable appearance of this tab "System Center Endpoint Protection wants to reset your settings"?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome offers to Reset browser settings if it detects a Browser Hijack.

Simply delete the below registry key on your system and it should work.
CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\TriggeredReset